# Total sum all nodes by key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I use `anglar-ui-tree` in my project.

How can I sum all `companyEstimatedEarning` for each node?

For example, `company 1.1.1` - `total=5`, `company 1.1` - `total=18`, `company 1` - `total=53`

```
$scope.data = [{
    'id': 1,
    'title': 'company1',
    'companyEstimatedEarning': 25,
    'nodes': [
        {
            'id': 11,
            'title': 'company1.1',
            'companyEstimatedEarning': 13,
            'nodes': [
                {
                    'id': 111,
                    'title': 'company1.1.1',
                    'companyEstimatedEarning': 5,
                    'nodes': []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'id': 12,
            'title': 'company1.2',
            'companyEstimatedEarning': 10,
            'nodes': []
        }
    ]
}, {
    'id': 2,
    'title': 'company2',
    'companyEstimatedEarning': 10,
    'nodes': [
        {
            'id': 21,
            'title': 'company2.1',
            'companyEstimatedEarning': 15,
            'nodes': []
        }
    ]
}];
```